# Par function underlying logic

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

How does the `par` function work? Its signature is:

```
par :: a -> b -> b.
```

But this is strange. Why isn't it:

`par :: (a -> b) -> a -> b`

(get function, execute it in new thread and return result) ?

Another question, is this normal haskell multithreading??

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`par` is for speculative parallelism, and relies on laziness.

You speculate that the unevaluated `a` should be computed while you're busy working on `b`.

Later in your program you might refer to `a` again, and it will be ready.

Here's an example. We wish to add 3 numbers together. Each number is expensive to compute. We can compute them in parallel, then add them together:

```
main = a `par` b `par` c `pseq` print (a + b + c)
    where
        a = ack 3 10
        b = fac 42
        c = fib 34

fac 0 = 1
fac n = n * fac (n-1)

ack 0 n = n+1
ack m 0 = ack (m-1) 1
ack m n = ack (m-1) (ack m (n-1))

fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

Comment: Its valid usage? : someFunc a b = par (a^4) (replicate (a^4) b)

Comment: @Seraph That's useless for two reasons: (1) There is no guaranteed sharing between the two copies of `a^4` so evaluating one of them won't help the other (GHC *might* decide to share them anyway, I am not sure.) (2) The very first thing the `replicate` function does is to evaluate its first argument, so there won't be any time for it to be preevaluted by the `par`.

Comment: damn... Can you please write some nice example with par function?

Comment: It's correct to rewrite it like this ? : `fun = par a.par b.par c $ (a+b+c) where a = ack 3 10 ; b = fac 42 ; c = fib 34`

Comment: @Seraph That is better, since those are more expensive computations. Also a formatting hint: to get ``a `par` b `par` c `par` a+b+c`` in SO, use *double* backquotes around the whole code.

Answer (score 4):

Because we don't "execute functions" in Haskell. We evaluate values, that's how we control processor activity. What `par x y` does is basically: while evaluating the result `y`, the runtime will also already pre-evaluate `x` though that's itself not asked for yet.

Note that this isn't necessarily the nicest way of writing parallel code now. Check out newer alternatives like the [`Eval` monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.0.4/docs/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#t%3aEval). You may want to read [Simon Marlow's book](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous answers it is worth pointing out that `a` and `b` will be evaluated to *weak head normal form (WHNF)* only (i.e. applying the outermost reduction or constructor), so it could be useful to force evaluation using `deepseq`.

In terms of operational semantics `par` creates a *spark* which is a pointer to a thunk (unevaluated computation) and added to the spark pool. This is very cheap and it is possible to have millions of sparks. Thread creation is advisory, the run time system can decide not to turn `a` into thread and prune superfluos parallelism by ignoring the spark or by subsuming the child spark in the parent.

The picture you show could indicate an issue with your code, where thread executed on CPU2 has significantly less work to do (load imbalance).